# Spring Security and Okta

Tags: spring-security, okta

I've read several blogs about this subject and all the stackoverflow.com articles I can get my hands on, but nothing seems to answer the problem I've been encountering.

I've followed several Okta examples online, including the main [blog](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/03/16/spring-boot-saml) post that was posted this year.  I still run into the issue below, which when I trace through the spring-security code gets me to the voting process in spring and it fails.

```
TRACE 2017-08-22 16:45:11,128 [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] - Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: org.springframework.security.access.event.AuthorizationFailureEvent[source=FilterInvocation: URL: /SSO]
DEBUG 2017-08-22 16:45:11,129 [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter] - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:206)
```

In my setup I'm not using spring boot or spring annotations, but rather good ol' spring xml configuration.  I've look at the configuration enough that I don't see where the issue lies.

versions:
spring:           3.2.18.RELEASE
spring security:  3.2.7.RELEASE
spring saml2:     1.0.2.RELEASE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<!-- Enable auto-wiring 
<context:annotation-config/>-->

<!-- Scan for auto-wiring classes in spring saml packages -->
<context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.security.saml"/>

<!-- Unsecured pages -->
<security:http security="none" pattern="/favicon.ico"/>
<security:http security="none" pattern="/images/**"/>
<security:http security="none" pattern="/style/**"/>
<security:http security="none" pattern="/scripts/**"/>
<security:http security="none" pattern="/logout.jsp"/>

<!-- Security for the administration UI -->
<security:http pattern="/saml/web/**" use-expressions="false">
    <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/saml/web/metadata/login"/>
    <security:form-login login-processing-url="/saml/web/login" login-page="/saml/web/metadata/login" default-target-url="/saml/web/metadata"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/saml/web/metadata/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/saml/web/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <security:custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/>
</security:http>

<!-- Secured pages with SAML as entry point -->
<security:http entry-point-ref="samlEntryPoint" use-expressions="false">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
    <security:custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/>
    <security:custom-filter after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="samlFilter"/>
</security:http>

<!-- Filters for processing of SAML messages -->
<bean id="samlFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <security:filter-chain-map request-matcher="ant">
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/login/**" filters="samlEntryPoint"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/logout/**" filters="samlLogoutFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/metadata/**" filters="metadataDisplayFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSO/**" filters="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSOHoK/**" filters="samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SingleLogout/**" filters="samlLogoutProcessingFilter"/>
        <!-- <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/discovery/**" filters="samlIDPDiscovery"/> -->
    </security:filter-chain-map>
</bean>

<!-- Handler deciding where to redirect user after successful login -->
<bean id="successRedirectHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/app/buildingInformation"/>
</bean>
<!--
Use the following for interpreting RelayState coming from unsolicited response as redirect URL:
<bean id="successRedirectHandler" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLRelayStateSuccessHandler">
   <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/" />
</bean>-->

<!-- Handler deciding where to redirect user after failed login -->
<bean id="failureRedirectHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <property name="useForward" value="true"/>
    <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/error.jsp"/>
</bean>

<!-- Handler for successful logout -->
<bean id="successLogoutHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/logout.jsp"/>
</bean>

<!-- <bean id="mySecurityUserService" class="com.my.security.service.MySecurityUserService">
   <property name="application" ref="application"/>
   <property name="allowAllAccess" ref="allowAllAccess"/>
</bean> -->

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <!-- Register authentication manager for SAML provider -->
    <security:authentication-provider ref="samlAuthenticationProvider"/>
    <!-- Register authentication manager for administration UI 
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="mySecurityUserService"/>-->
</security:authentication-manager>

<!-- Logger for SAML messages and events -->
<bean id="samlLogger" class="org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger"/>

<!-- Central storage of cryptographic keys -->
<bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
    <constructor-arg value="classpath:security/mykeystore.jks"/>
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="secret"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="spring" value="secret"/>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="spring"/>
</bean>

<!-- Entry point to initialize authentication, default values taken from properties file -->
<bean id="samlEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint">
    <property name="defaultProfileOptions">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileOptions">
            <property name="includeScoping" value="false"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- IDP Discovery Service -->
<bean id="samlIDPDiscovery" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLDiscovery">
    <property name="idpSelectionPath" value="/WEB-INF/security/idpSelection.jsp"/>
</bean>

<!-- Filter automatically generates default SP metadata -->
<bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator">
            <property name="extendedMetadata">
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                    <!-- <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="true"/> -->
                    <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="false"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<!-- The filter is waiting for connections on URL suffixed with filterSuffix and presents SP metadata there -->
<bean id="metadataDisplayFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataDisplayFilter"/>

<!-- Configure HTTP Client to accept certificates from the keystore for HTTPS verification -->
<!--
<bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.trust.httpclient.TLSProtocolConfigurer">
    <property name="sslHostnameVerification" value="default"/>
</bean>
-->

<!-- IDP Metadata configuration - paths to metadata of IDPs in circle of trust is here -->
<bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <!-- Example of classpath metadata with Extended Metadata -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider">
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <bean class="java.util.Timer"/>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <bean class="org.opensaml.util.resource.ClasspathResource">
                                <constructor-arg value="/metadata/idp.xml"/>
                            </bean>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
            <!-- Example of HTTP metadata without Extended Metadata -->
            <!-- <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider">
                URL containing the metadata
                <constructor-arg>
                    <value type="java.lang.String">https://dev-738438.oktapreview.com/app/exkbq3s0o4HnCFf3U0h7/sso/saml/metadata</value>
                </constructor-arg>
                Timeout for metadata loading in ms
                <constructor-arg>
                    <value type="int">15000</value>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
            </bean> -->
            <!-- Example of file system metadata without Extended Metadata -->
            <!--
            <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <value type="java.io.File">/usr/local/metadata/idp.xml</value>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
            </bean>
            -->
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
    <!-- OPTIONAL used when one of the metadata files contains information about this service provider -->
    <!-- <property name="hostedSPName" value=""/> -->
    <!-- OPTIONAL property: can tell the system which IDP should be used for authenticating user by default. -->
    <!-- <property name="defaultIDP" value="http://localhost:8080/opensso"/> -->
</bean>

<!-- SAML Authentication Provider responsible for validating of received SAML messages -->
<bean id="samlAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider">
    <!-- OPTIONAL property: can be used to store/load user data after login 
    <property name="userDetails" ref="mySecurityUserService"/> -->
</bean>

<!-- Provider of default SAML Context -->
<bean id="contextProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderImpl"/>

<!-- Processing filter for WebSSO profile messages -->
<bean id="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successRedirectHandler"/>
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureRedirectHandler"/>
</bean>

<!-- Processing filter for WebSSO Holder-of-Key profile -->
<bean id="samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successRedirectHandler"/>
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureRedirectHandler"/>
</bean>

<!-- Logout handler terminating local session -->
<bean id="logoutHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler">
    <property name="invalidateHttpSession" value="false"/>
</bean>

<!-- Override default logout processing filter with the one processing SAML messages -->
<bean id="samlLogoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="successLogoutHandler"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="logoutHandler"/>
    <constructor-arg index="2" ref="logoutHandler"/>
</bean>

<!-- Filter processing incoming logout messages -->
<!-- First argument determines URL user will be redirected to after successful global logout -->
<bean id="samlLogoutProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="successLogoutHandler"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="logoutHandler"/>
</bean>

<!-- Class loading incoming SAML messages from httpRequest stream -->
<bean id="processor" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="redirectBinding"/>
            <ref bean="postBinding"/>
            <ref bean="artifactBinding"/>
            <ref bean="soapBinding"/>
            <ref bean="paosBinding"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<!-- SAML 2.0 WebSSO Assertion Consumer -->
<bean id="webSSOprofileConsumer" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl"/>

<!-- SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key WebSSO Assertion Consumer -->
<bean id="hokWebSSOprofileConsumer" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl"/>

<!-- SAML 2.0 Web SSO profile -->
<bean id="webSSOprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileImpl"/>

<!-- SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key Web SSO profile -->
<bean id="hokWebSSOProfile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl"/>

<!-- SAML 2.0 ECP profile -->
<bean id="ecpprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileECPImpl"/>

<!-- SAML 2.0 Logout Profile -->
<bean id="logoutprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.SingleLogoutProfileImpl"/>

<!-- Bindings, encoders and decoders used for creating and parsing messages -->
<bean id="postBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPostBinding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine"/>
</bean>

<bean id="redirectBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
</bean>

<bean id="artifactBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPArtifactBinding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager"/>
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
            <property name="processor">
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl">
                    <constructor-arg ref="soapBinding"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="soapBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPSOAP11Binding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
</bean>

<bean id="paosBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPAOS11Binding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
</bean>

<!-- Initialization of OpenSAML library-->
<bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap"/>

<!-- Initialization of the velocity engine -->
<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.security.saml.util.VelocityFactory" factory-method="getEngine"/>

<!-- 
    XML parser pool needed for OpenSAML parsing
    WARNING: If customizing a ParserPool implementation See https://shibboleth.net/community/advisories/secadv_20131213.txt
             Specifically the following should be explicitly set to avoid exploits:

             1) set pool property 'expandEntityReferences' to 'false'
             2) set feature 'javax.xml.XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING' to true
             3) set feature 'http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl' to true. This is a Xerces-specific feature,
                including derivatives such as the internal JAXP implementations supplied with the Oracle and OpenJDK JREs. For
                other JAXP implementations, consult the documentation for the implementation for guidance on how to achieve a
                similar configuration.
-->
<bean id="parserPool" class="org.opensaml.xml.parse.StaticBasicParserPool" init-method="initialize"/>

<bean id="parserPoolHolder" class="org.springframework.security.saml.parser.ParserPoolHolder"/>
```

Thanks in advance for any help or for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This guide is a bit old, but it shows how to make things work with good ol' Spring XML: https://developer.okta.com/code/java/spring_security_saml.html

Comment: I did look over the guide you specified, it was a great help.  I also debugged into the spring security code, and found that it never calls into the SamlAuthenticationProvider.  It fails prior, which is the error I provided above.

Comment: I guess that's where I'm kind of stuck.  It seems like I have all the pieces in place.  I have also bumped up my logging to trace to see what I can get out of my logs.